# Unknown MCU in LQFP 100 package

Tags: microcontroller, identification, surface-mount, can

Does someone recognize this microcontroller?

- It has 100 pins, and looks like LQFP package.
- UART is 5V out, so it's not 3v3 IC.
- It also has 2 CAN channels.

https://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1005
gives ATSAMV70/71 but they fail 5V criteria, so I don't think it's Microchip.

[image]

Comment: looks like custom silicon to me. What makes you think it is a microcontroller? What does the unit do?

Comment: CAN immobiliser for cars, listens for CAN messages and generates response. It does have bootloader. Also if it was custom then they wouldn't have scraped the text off, but put their own name on it I guess.  Even manufacturer would help. It is the database is updatable via uart, and there is a programming header with full jtag I think.

Comment: Is there a secret regarding this? Why are you holding back information? Or are you going to drip feed us?

Comment: No one is going to be able to look at a random LQFN100 that's had it's silk screen ablated off, and tell you what it is unless they've already done the work you seem to want to do. The bare minimum you will have to do (aside from getting lucky) is reverse the schematic from the board that'll constrain some of the pins and help narrow down from the thousands of possibilities that exist.

Comment: Looks like it's the RH850 series, the 3circles gave it away. Not many MCUs run on 5V.